# What is the best for a honeymoon destination in August?

Tags: europe, asia

Italy, Spain, Malaysia or Thailand? And how are beaches in Italy?

Comment: And how are beaches in Italy?: crowded !!

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I don't know Malaysia or Thailand; but at least check the expected weather; as far as I can google, there should be a lot of rain in August in Thailand.

I would not go to Spain or Italy in August; it is height of the summer vacations; tons of people, lots or seasonal closures in the cities.

If really wanting to go to Italy, I'd go to Sicily or Sardinia.

Comment: Thank you :D are there any other recommended destinations other than the ones I’ve mentioned ?